# How to add dynamic number of sub items to android recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a requirement in which there will be multiple child items to a RecycylerView Item.  As per the requirement a single recycler view item can have maximum of four horizontal Childs and 2 vertical Childs at max. I have used recyclerview inside a recyclerview to achieve this by the results are not per the requirement. In short I need something like this [image]

The results of recyclerview inside recyclerview is something like this. The items are not stretching to full length as highlighted in yellow.

[image]

How can I achieve this? I have user grid layout manager on inner recyclerview with spancount of 3 and tried with 4 as well.  Converted to linearlayout manger horizontal but not able to get the desired result.

Comment: Post your activity and adapter code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GridLayoutManager` for this. Just call the `setSpanSizeLookup` method and determine how many columns an item should take.

Comment: He would need to recreate active item. You would't create such behavior just with `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: Or he can use [flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)